# How do you express a Python Callable with no arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

In the docs for the Python `typing` package, it [says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable):

> It is possible to declare the return type of a callable without specifying the call signature by substituting a literal ellipsis for the list of arguments in the type hint: `Callable[..., ReturnType].`

On the other hand, it [also says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable):

> `Callable[..., ReturnType]` (literal ellipsis) can be used to type hint a callable taking any number of arguments and returning ReturnType.

I want to express a function that takes no arguments but returns a string. The ellipsis seems to indicate that there are some unspecified arguments. I want to express that that there definately are zero arguements.

Do I have any alternatives to using `Callable[..., str]` in my type hint?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It requires a sequence of argument types, so if there are no types, you pass it an empty sequence:

```
Callable[[], str]
```